# maps api3 load xml marker delay

Tags: xml, google-maps-api-3, settimeout

i´ve made a [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3?hl=de-DE) from google maps api to load markers from database and php with a generated xml file to the map. Now i am trying to add a delay with setTimeout or so to drop one marker after another like this [example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations-iteration?hl=el-GR). I very beginner and would very happy if someone can tell me how to do this!

```
downloadUrl("php/addLocations.php", function (data) {
    var xml = parseXml(data);
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
        var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
        var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
        var profile_image = markers[i].getAttribute("myimage");
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")), parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
        var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address + "<br/>" + "<img src='uploads/" + profile_image + "' width='100px' />";
        var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
        var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: bigmap,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            shadow: icon.shadow
        });
        bindInfoWindow(marker2, bigmap, infoWindowLoc, html);
    }
});


var infoWindowLoc = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

function bindInfoWindow(marker2, bigmap, infoWindowLoc, html) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function () {
        //openMarkerBox(); 
        // panning map
        bigmap.panTo(marker2.position);
        infoWindowLoc.setContent(html);
        infoWindowLoc.open(bigmap, marker2);
    });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request.responseText, request.status);
        }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
}

function parseXml(str) {
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
        doc.loadXML(str);
        return doc;
    } else if (window.DOMParser) {
        return (new DOMParser).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
    }
}

function doNothing() {
    alert("shit")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you inspect the code at your [example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations-iteration?hl=el-GR), everything you need is there. Take a look at:

1 - The `onclick` handler that is attached to the *Drop Markers* button:

```
`<button id="drop" onclick="drop()">Drop Markers</button>`
```

Online documentation for `onclick` is available: [at this link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp).

2 - The `drop()` function from your example:

```
function drop() {
    for (var i = 0; i < neighborhoods.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            addMarker();
        }, i * 200);
    }
}
```

Online documentation for the `setTimeout` function is available: [at this link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).

3 - The `addMarker()` function from your example:

```
function addMarker() {
    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        position:  neighborhoods[iterator],
        map:       map,
        draggable: false,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    }));
    iterator++;
}
```

Online documentation for `google.maps.marker` animation is available: [at this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#MarkerAnimations).

Walk through the code, dig in a little, and you should be able to figure this out.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! i have tryed a lot of things. 
When I put the seTimeout into the downloadUrl function i always become the Error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getAttribute' of undefined
(anonymous function)

Comment: It's impossible to help you without being able to see your new version of the `downloadUrl` function.

Comment: One thing I notice right away: within `setTimeout` you are calling `addMarker` before you have created the vars that are passed to that function.

Comment: When i call the function after setting the vars there is been the same error :-(

Comment: At this point, I don't think there is much more I can do to help you while you are making edits and working your way through a debugging effort. If you believe my answer addressed your original question, it's customary to click the arrow shape next to the question.

Comment: i´am sorry, i ve been for the first time here.

Comment: I dont understand really. All what i want to do is: 
the page loads, the downloadUrl function calls and loads the xml file. There should be the delay. I ve spend a lot af hours to fix this problem, but my skills a very limited ... 
But i still thanks to spend your time for me!

Comment: I am glad to have helped, but I can tell that your skills are limiting your ability to move forward. But it gets to the point where it's not realistic to keep working here on stackoverflow, when you are debugging code line-by-line.

Comment: What do you mean with "debugging code line-by-line."? Should i post the whole application or what?

Comment: I mean that if you have a specific question about how to do something or asking for help with one problem, stackoverflow makes sense. It does not make sense to ask a question, write some code, get an error, add a comment to an existing question, make a change, get an error, add a comment to an existing question, etc. This forum isn't a realistic place to deal with debugging a program. You have to take over that part yourself.

Comment: Okay thats makes sense. :-)
Next time i would be a bit more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here is a solution thats seems to work.
Thank you Sean 4 your time and tipps.

```
var iterator = 0;
var marker2;
var customIcons = {art: {icon: 'img/art_marker.png',},graff: {icon: 'img/graff_marker.png',}};

downloadUrl("php/addLocations.php", function (data) {
    var xml = parseXml(data);
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

    myFunction();
    function myFunction() { 
        var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
        var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
        var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
        var profile_image = markers[i].getAttribute("myimage");
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")), parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));

        setTimeout(function() { 
            addMarker(name, address, type, profile_image, point);
}, i * 2200);

    }

}
});

function addMarker (name, address, type, profile_image, point) {

        var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
        var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address + "<br/>" + "<img src='uploads/" + profile_image + "' width='100px' />";
        var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: bigmap,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            shadow: icon.shadow
        });
        bindInfoWindow(marker2, bigmap, infoWindowLoc, html);
        iterator++;
}
```